# Favorite BSE post of the year - 2017

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

Well the winter bash is almost over and the [hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/304341/278094) are nearly gone, that means the year is close to its end and it's time to look back.
**What was your favorite post from BSE this year?**
Question or answer, post the link as an answer below.
By favorite I mean anything you found awesome, learned something new, was surprised by, impressed, etc.

This is not necessary a best of list, more like the most memorable post from 2017.

What a year BSE has had. We have had 12,098 questions and 9,435 answers (and [counting](http://data.stackexchange.com/blender/query/775356)).
Here's to an even better 2018!

Comment: Well to get things started off, [Volumetric Windows 10 logo effect](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/72010/2217) by Rich Sedman. A great answer.

Comment: Should the answers be comments or answers?

Comment: [Trace visualisation in 3D - how to wrap curves onto a 3D mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/94991/trace-visualisation-in-3d-how-to-wrap-curves-onto-a-3d-mesh/95577#95577) by @OmarAhmad one of the brightest answers in this site.

Comment: @David Are self-nominations allowed?

Comment: @ScottMilner sure.

Answer (score 9):

Ok because SE auto converts to comments "trivial answers" (answers with links to other answers) I guess there will be one answer with a list of links.

Add your favorite post to the list below.

- [Volumetric Windows 10 logo effect](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/72010/2217) by Rich Sedman - David's pick
- [Trace visualisation in 3D - how to wrap curves onto a 3D mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/94991/trace-visualisation-in-3d-how-to-wrap-curves-onto-a-3d-mesh/95577#95577) by OmarAhmad - cegaton's pick
- [Rounded Indentation on Cyclinder](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81596/how-can-i-make-a-rounded-indentation-on-a-cylinder/81605#81605) by Paul Gonet - Duarte's pick
- [Mix colors from different objects at collision (Rigid Bodies and Particles)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/79575/26640) by Scott Milner - self-nomination